# Define InputBindings in Style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, listboxitem, inputbinding

I would like to add a right click and left click command to each `ListBoxItem` in a `Style`.  Is this possible?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="InputBindings">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MouseBinding Command="{x:Static View:Commands.AddItem}"
                          MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
            <MouseBinding Command="{x:Static View:Commands.RemoveItem}"
                          MouseAction="RightClick"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining InputBindings within a Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660760/defining-inputbindings-within-a-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to accomplish what I originally wanted.  I ended up using Events instead of Commands.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="AssignItem"/>
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="RemoveItem"/>
</Style>
```