# How to make leftdouble click work on entire treeviewitem area not just on text?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have a TreeView and i use an ItemTemplate for the Item Bindings similar to this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItemCollection}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}"></MouseBinding>
                </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In the Ui it looks something like this :[image: TreeView UI]

Now if i doubleclick on the text the command triggers. When i doubleclick on the grey area nothing happens. How can i achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Apply the `InputBinding` in the `ControlTemplate` of the `TreeViewItem`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660760/defining-inputbindings-within-a-style

Comment: Where can i get the default control template? Is there something similar to style.basedon attribute?

Comment: What style/template are you currently using? It doesn't look like the default one.

Comment: Materialdesigninxamlthemes.

Comment: Please state this in your question the next time. See my answer for a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Define an `ItemContainerStyle` that stretches the content and removes the default padding, and then put the `StackPanel` in an element that adds the padding back:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItemCollection}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="8">
                <Border.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
                </Border.InputBindings>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work, but it looks much nicer.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Did you set the `Background` of the `Border`? In fact, you can just copy and paste my example. It works for me, i.e. the command is fired when I click outside the text.

Comment: Okay thats weird, cause i pretty much copied your code. Working hours are unfortunately over for me. Ill take another look at it tomorrow.

Comment: No, it doesn't work unfortunately. Ive tested it in a seperate project as well. I want the grey area like in the picture to be clickable

Comment: I found a "solution" by setting property of width of treeviewitem to binding ActualWidth of ancestor treeviewitem and binding width of border to width of ancestor treeviewitem. problem with that is that it has a really really bad performance so i cant use that

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue because it works for me. Please provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell me where I should click.